# Key is stuck and car will only go into reverse

Tags: ford, transmission, key

The day before yesterday my key was stuck in my ignition, and the steering wheel wouldn't lock. I tried to take it out but didn't want to damage it so I left it in there. Yesterday I went to drive the car and it would only move in reverse and when I put it in drive it wouldn't move at all. I checked all fluids and everything is good. What could be the issue?

Comment: It sounds like the shifting mechanism isn't working. If you provided complete vehicle information, I'm sure we could actually point to where you should look. We would need year/model/engine. If you feel funky, throw in the mileage. BTW, welcome to the site! We're glad you're here and I'm sure we can help!

Comment: Key / shift interlock issue. Step # 1. Read the owners manual.